# MS ACCESS: Report from multiple related tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an Access DB with multiple related tables (i.e. Ta and Tb where records of Tb relate to records of Ta). I am trying to create a report where all the available data are listed in rows. However it does only depict data having records in both (Ta and Tb) I mean if I have a record in Ta which has no record related in Tb this is not depicted in the report. I wish it was instead depicted with empty or default values.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you want exactly, but it seems like you are wanting to try a LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already stated by Matt in his comment, you have to join the tables via `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT Ta.SomeColumn, Tb.SomeColumn
FROM Ta
LEFT JOIN Tb ON Ta.SomeColumn = Tb.SomeColumn
```

This shows rows in `Ta` that have no counterpart in `Tb`.
If it's the other way round (rows in `Tb` that have no counterpart in `Ta`) you have to use `RIGHT JOIN` instead.